# How to force NavigationLink to recreate destination?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a menu view where I push a game view. When I dismiss game view and push it again, the pushed view is old game view. I want it to be a new view. How to do this?

```
struct MenuView: View {
    
    @State private var showGameView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: gameView,
                    isActive: $showGameView) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                Button {
                    showGameView = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Play")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
    
    @MainActor
    @ViewBuilder private var gameView: some View {
        let gameModel = MyGameModel.myGameModel()
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(gameModel)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you targeting iOS 15 or below? If not, you should not use `NavigationView` and that overload of `NavigationLink.init`.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm targeting iOS 15. I tired using NavigationStack and navigationDestination but i get the same problem.

Comment: `ContentView` should not take an environment object. Since you want the game model to live no longer than `ContentView`, it should be a `@StateObject`, initialised inside `ContentView`. Is there anything preventing you from doing that?

Comment: The only safe way to create models in a View is with State or StateObject. You shouldn’t be creating them in a ViewBuilder. You should look at some of the basic tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather using an `@EnvironmentObject`, you should make the `MyGameModel` a `@StateObject` in `ContentView`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = MyGameModel.myGameModel()
    // rather than:
    // @EnvironmentObject var model: MyGameModel

    ...
}
```

This causes `model` to be initialised with `MyGameModel.myGameModel()`, and the previous game model object (if any) to be deinitialised, whenever a new `ContentView` is (re)created.